# Is Android Studio backward compatible with older API? (specifically, need to target older API (27) with Android Studio 3.6.3 )

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Is Android Studio backward compatible with older API?

More specifically,
I need to target **API 27 with Android Studio 3.6.3.**

I am unable to do so. Why?

*Note: I am aware that I would not be able to publish to Play Store. This is not a problem for me.*

As stated here - https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

> Although the Android plugin is typically updated in lock-step with
>   Android Studio, the plugin (and the rest of the Gradle system) can run
>   independent of Android Studio and be updated separately.

And in Upgrade Gradle section, in the table

Plugin Version 3.2.0 - 3.2.1 works with Gradle version 4.6+

**My set up:**

**Settings.gradle**

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-bin.zip

**In apps build.grade:**

SDKs/Build tools are set as:

> compileSdkVersion 27 buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
>
> minSdkVersion 27 targetSdkVersion 27

And Dependencies:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0' i
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
```

**Build.gradle (project)**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {

       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
}
```

But I get the following:

> The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.2) is ignored, as
>   it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle
>   Plugin 3.2.1.

Why is that? Surely I was able to target 27 with that plug in version in older versions of AS.

And when I build:

> error: failed linking references. (No additional detail in logs)

Note: Trying with even lower versions of Build Tools and Android Gradle Plug Ins (and targeting lower api) gives the same error. Downgrading the gradle version doesn't work either (tried with 4.6)

Note 2: Trying with the latest versions (accepting what AS 3.6.3 gives you by default, which is gradle-5.6.4,  buildToolsVersion "29.0.2") gives the below error.
This is easy to reproduce - just create a new project (choose empty activity to reduce dependencies), use legacy support libraries, and change compile and target SDK to 27

> .../appcompat-v7-28.0.0/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT:
>   error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

Does it mean you just cannot target anything below 28 with AS 3.6.3? What role would AS play here if the building blocks here are Build Tools and Android Gradle Plug in (as stated above), which I can choose as I please, and yet to no effect?

And just want to note: no, I don't want to update to api 28. I need specifically below 28, and my current version of AS is 3.6.3.

Is there no way out and have to use an older AS? And if the latter, what would then be the role of AS in this?

Comment: "I need to target API 27 with Android Studio 3.6.3" -- you will not be able to ship your app on the Play Store and some other channels with an older `targetSdkVersion` like that. Beyond that, use a modern Gradle plugin (and matching Gradle version), plus get rid of the `buildToolsVersion`. You can still use older `compileSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, and dependency versions.

Comment: this particular app is not for Play Store or any official channels. I did start with the latest gradle originally and the matching gradle plugin, same problem, that's when I started downgrading.

Answer (score 1):

Tool versions are largely independent of your `targetSdkVersion`, you don't need `buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"` for a target sdk of 27

Edit your app's build.gradle to use modern versions of the build tools, and then set `targetSdkVersion 27`

Note that you will not be able to deploy to the Play Store with this as the minimum target is now 28 (current as of 5/13/2020) source: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk

The following is a portion of a valid app module build.gradle targeting sdk 27

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mikedg.dekudeals"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

The following is a portion of the buildscript from the project build.gradle that works with it

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

If the above does not work, I recommend looking into migrating to the androidx libraries instead of the old support libraries. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#additional_resources
I don't think this should cause problems, but can't confidently say that it wouldn't

Comment: as I mentioned in my other comments, I am aware of the limitation of not being able to publish to the play store and it doesn't matter, it is not intended for that. You say here is a sample of a default config, but there is nothing there. can you add it please? Because again I did try originally with the modern versions, and it had the same result

Comment: @Dmitri sorry about that, I added the missing content, also a note about migrating the support libraries to their androidx counterparts if the versions in my samples don't help. Also, if you can post your build errors if this doesn't work, that would be great,

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. that's the same configuration I tried with in the beginning, and had a different error (that's when I started experimenting with downgrading gradle/plug in versions), the error is /appcompat-1.0.0/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource  android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found. Somehow v28 is still brought into the picture. :

Comment: dependencies are the same  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'